# Как перекрыть опцию gcc в make?

Tags: makefile, gcc

Проект содержит несколько make-файлов. Один из включаемых make-файлов устанавливает опцию gcc std99. И это правильно. Но нужно один из файлов собрать без этой опции. Как эту опцию отменить?

**Добавление.**

Во включаемом make-файле определяется команда:

```
define build
$(CC) \
    -std99 \
    ... \
    -o $@
endef
```

а во включаещем make-файле эта команда используется:

```
$(MODULE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(build)
```

Comment: Так это ведь зависит от того, как сборка поставлена. Недостаточно информации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от make-файлов (в том числе от того, как "один из" "устанавливает").
Если можно, отрывки из make-файлов pls.
Отрывок из описания make:

---

9.5 Overriding Variables

An argument that contains ‘=’ specifies the value of a variable: ‘v=x’ sets the value of the variable v to x. If you specify a value in this way, all ordinary assignments of the same variable in the makefile are ignored; we say they have been overridden by the command line argument.

The most common way to use this facility is to pass extra flags to compilers. For example, in a properly written makefile, the variable CFLAGS is included in each recipe that runs the C compiler, so a file foo.c would be compiled something like this:

```
 cc -c $(CFLAGS) foo.c
```

Thus, whatever value you set for CFLAGS affects each compilation that occurs. The makefile probably specifies the usual value for CFLAGS, like this:

```
 CFLAGS=-g
```

Each time you run make, you can override this value if you wish. For example, if you say ‘make CFLAGS='-g -O'’, each C compilation will be done with ‘cc -c -g -O’. (This also illustrates how you can use quoting in the shell to enclose spaces and other special characters in the value of a variable when you override it.)

The variable CFLAGS is only one of many standard variables that exist just so that you can change them this way. See Variables Used by Implicit Rules, for a complete list.

В вашем случае придётся в командной строке определять переменную build:

make build='$(CC) <опции>' <цель>

Примечание: -std99 - это что? -std=c99 или -std=gnu99?

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно для приведённого случая

```
$(MODULE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(filter-out -std99,$(build))
```

Хотя на мой взгляд, лучше переделать Makefile в сторону большей гибкости.